# Lua Equivalent for NumPy and SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, lua

I'm thinking of learning lua, i learned that it is a smaller language compared to python and has an efficient JIT compiler implementation in the form LuaJIT.

I would like to know is it possible to use lua the way i use python with Numpy+Scipy.
further if Lua has numpy+scipy equivalent does it have a matplotlib equivalent?

Comment: Irrelevant, but since your summary sounds like Python doesn't have a JIT-compiling implementation: There's PyPy (which also supports a considerable and growing subset of NumPy).

Comment: ok pypy , isn't as fast as LuaJIT, also i would like to learn a language , which i could completely grok, possibly at some point implement a "toy" interpreter. know there are lies, damn lies and benchmarks but i belive shootout.alioth benchmarks  are OK.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with learning another language - quite the contrary. I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: probably you are gonnabe onlyone who gets (comment)upvoted for nitpicking, by me.

Comment: Also take a look at Torch (http://www.torch.ch/) which aims to be a Matlab-like library for Lua, but also offers abstractions akin to Theano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [numlua](https://github.com/carvalho/numlua), but since it depends on BLAS/LAPACK, FFTW, and HDF5, LuaJIT will not buy you any performance gain with numlua per se.

Comment: can it even be used with LuaJIT?like numpy can't right now be used with pypy, though work is underway.is luarocks something like a package manager for lua?

Comment: LuaJIT is compatible with Lua 5.1 including the C library interface, so I see no reason you couldn't use numlua with LuaJIT

Answer (score 7):

there is something else, i found something similar to Scipy+matplotlib for Lua,i'm not sure how active development is last release was in January 2011, it is [GSL-shell](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/) 
it leverages the GSL library and has plotting capabilities , it is more like matlab than scipy+matplotlib.

Answer (score 5):

I am authoring the Lunum project, which has no dependencies and can be used as a shared module or embedded in other C applications.

It's in active development, and used in serious physics research. It supports a good subset of the Numpy semantics. Array slicing will be ready in the next release.

https://github.com/jzrake/lunum

Comment: Will it support arbitrary lower bounds?

Comment: Short: I can make this feature available almost immediately. Would you like me to?

Long: That's a good question. Numpy does not, and my general intention is to adhere to Numpy behavior wherever possible. However! Fortran 90 DOES support arbitrary lower bounds on arrays, and borrowing from that paradigm sounds quite plausible. By the way, I do computational fluid dynamics, where the lower bounds on arrays are sometimes desired to be negative to enforce the idea of 'ghost' zones, where boundary conditions are applied.

Comment: I have the same background in CFD with ghost zones, that's why I am curious. I will probably not use Lua in the near future so do not make your decisions for me. You could probably use negative indexes for counting from the end, as in Python, if you stay with Lua standard counting from 1. I am now even considering writing a derivative of a Python ndarray with Fortran like indexing for me :)

Comment: (Now I realized that Lua + maybe Lunum might be a good way for user supplied parts of code. Now I am trying Scheme, but it is not ideal.)

Comment: I don't know about Scheme, but I can say from experience that Lua has been an incredible tool for science application building. Unlike Python, you get complete control of how the interpreter is built, and the C API is very easy. My research code uses Lua as a sort of glorified configuration language, but over time I give more control to Lua, as my code becomes more of a Lua extension. It uses Lunum to retrieve data from the application's internals and perform post-processing and I/O through HDF5.

Comment: I think that re-indexing is a good feature for Lunum. I've already added it, and will have the code tested and tagged for release by tomorrow most likely.

Comment: @JonathanZrake OK , I'm not being mean here , i respect your work , wouldn't it be nice if you integrate your efforts with gsl-shell project , those guys have put in a lot of effort, wrapping gsl and some undocumented c++ code. short question: why one more Scipy wannabe for Lua?

Comment: The GSL shell is super solid solid stuff, it's just not what I needed. GSL shell is geared toward use as an independent application. I needed something which was (1) easily embedded in C code and (2) supports nd-arrays with slicing, the main use being to ferry data between core physics solvers in C, and higher level I/O or post-processing routines. BTW, the GSL shell does not contain a nd-array class with slicing, I wonder if they are interested in incorporating Lunum.

Answer (score 1):

I would also have a look at [SciLua](http://scilua.org/):

> A complete framework for numerical computing based on LuaJIT which combines the ease of use of scripting languages (MATLAB, R, ...) with the high performance of compiled languages (C/C++, Fortran, ...).